# How to install ATLAS on Kubuntu 18.04(Bionic)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

Things I've already tried:

**1. install all of this:**

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libblas3gf
> sudo apt-get install libblas-doc
> sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
> sudo apt-get install liblapack3gf
> sudo apt-get install liblapack-doc
> sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
> ```

And none of them were installed. I've receive this error message all the time

> E: Unable to locate package X

**2. Installing this**

> sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev

Also with an error message:

> Package liblapack-dev is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> Package libblas-dev is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libblas-dev' has no installation candidate E: Package
>   'liblapack-dev' has no installation candidate

**3. Trying to update my system and after that following the same steps
    as before again.**

> sudo apt-get update

But nothing had changed... Everything was staying exactly the same.

**4. Trying to install like this:**

> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

And of course again is not working and I get an error which sound like this

> E: Unable to locate package libatlas-base-dev

**My system:**

I'm using Kubunut 18.04

I was thinking that maybe is missing some repository and I don't know but how I can see it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libatlas-base-dev) is not.

Does any of you have any idea how can I fix this problem? If so, please let me know.

**Output of** `apt-cache policy libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev` **(after sudo add-apt-repository universe, sudo add-apt-repository main, sudo apt-get update)**

```
libatlas-base-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.10.3-5
  Version table:
     3.10.3-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
liblapack-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.1-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.7.1-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: It seems that you do not have *universe* repository. Lapack is in *main*. Try to add them with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, `sudo add-apt-repository main`, `sudo apt-get update` and then add output of `apt-cache policy libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev` to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you do not have *universe* repository (for `libatlas-base-dev`).
LAPACK and BLAS are in *main*. You should have both repositories enabled.

Try to add the repositories with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install needed packages with

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev
```